# How to clean an XML object to avoid the "Content not allowed in prolog" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, geoserver, sld

I have a XML object retrieved from an AJAX call and for which I have done some manipulations:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "url_of_xml",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (xml) {
                var sld_doc= $(xml)

                // manipulations with the XML file
            }
   })
```

The XML file is correctly modified and is how I need it to be (with the added/modified nodes). Now I need to POST the modified XML (to a GeoServer instance):

```
      $.ajax({
                url: "geoserver/rest/styles",
                type: 'POST',
                data: sld_doc,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml"
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {a
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    console.log(x.status + " " + x.responseText);
                }
            });
```

I'm getting the error: `500 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

From what I've read, it is caused by characters before the  tag at the beginning of the XML doc.

How can I clean the begging of the XML object so that it can be sent correctly to the server ? I'm able to access nodes with `sld_doc.find("node_name")` but how can I check for invalid characters before the 1st node (`<?xml>`) ?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of sld_doc after you have manipulated it?  Also, is the dataType for your POST meant to be xml?

Comment: How can I print the whole XML content from the XML object in javascript ? If I use `sld_doc[0].firstChild` or `sld_doc[0].documentElement` or `XMLSerializer().serializeToString(sld_doc[0])` I don't get the `<?xml>` node, I'm getting the one after

Comment: Yes the content that is sent to GeoServer needs to be XML, see: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/styles.html#styles-format

Comment: What happens if you just do:
console.log(sld_doc[0]);

Comment: It returns a `[object XMLDocument]` object

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are passing a jQuery object.  Try unwrapping it, and setting the right dataType too:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "geoserver/rest/styles",
    type: 'POST',
    data: sld_doc[0],
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml"
    },
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (data) {a
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do that I get `SCRIPT16389: Unhandled exception at line 8478, column 4 in http://localhost/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js
0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Unspecified error`

Comment: Any idea which line of your code is triggering that error?  I've just modified my answer so perhaps you could try that, and let me know what you see in your console?

Comment: I still get the JS runtime error when using the XML document in the request.... I don't know which line can cause the error since the XML document seems valid.

Comment: I've also added `process_data: false,` to the ajax call but stills gives me the Javascript error...